# How to draw thousands of polygons with random color using mapbox?

Tags: mapbox

I want to draw thousands of polygons with random color, how can I do it without creating tons of layers?
Now I use only one layer with MultiPolygon, it works fine, but I want same thing but filled with random colors.
How can I do that?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your demo?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, see this example: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/data-driven-circle-colors/

You can do the same, but you would have to add properties to the features that describe your polygons, that can be used to determine the color.

In this example the source holds circles. Their color is changed according to their `ethnicity` property in the source:

Sample source feature:

```
{
"type": "Feature",
"properties": {
"ethnicity": "White"
},
"geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [ -122.447303, 37.753574 ]
}
}
```

Adding all source features in 1 layer and adjusting color with `match` reference:

```js
map.addLayer({
'id': 'population',
'type': 'circle',
'source': 'ethnicity',
'source-layer': 'sf2010',
'paint': {
// make circles larger as the user zooms from z12 to z22
'circle-radius': {
'base': 1.75,
'stops': [
[12, 2],
[22, 180]
]
},
// color circles by ethnicity, using a match expression
// https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#expressions-match
'circle-color': [
'match',
['get', 'ethnicity'],
'White',
'#fbb03b',
'Black',
'#223b53',
'Hispanic',
'#e55e5e',
'Asian',
'#3bb2d0',
/* other */ '#ccc'
]
}
});
```